# Skip some arguments in a C++ function?

Tags: c++, optimization, arguments, default-arguments

I have a C++ function that has 5 arguments, all of which have default values.   If I pass in the first three arguments, the program will assign a default value to the last two arguments. Is there any way to pass 3 arguments, and skip one in the middle, giving values to say, the first, second, and fifth arguments?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: There are workarounds. But if you can, overload instead.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly, but you might be able to do something with std::bind:

```
int func(int arg1 = 0, int arg2 = 0, int arg3 = 0);

// elsewhere...
using std::bind;
using std::placeholders::_1;
auto f = bind(func, 0, _1, 0);

int result = f(3); // Call func(0, 3, 0);
```

The downside is of course that you are re-specifying the default parameters. I'm sure somebody else will come along with a more clever solution, but this could work if you're really desperate.

Answer (score 2):

With a classical 5 arguments function, there is no way to give it only 3 or 4. You can only write 3 or 4 with default arguments  but at the end you will get a function call with 5 arguments.

There are also issues with you system if there are several parameters with the same type.
For instance, if you have `foo(int a=4,int b=5)` and call `foo(10)`, how do you know you want to call `foo(10,5)` or `foo(4,10)` ?

With C++11 tuples  and [Named parameters idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Named_Parameter), you can cheat it a little bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

struct f_
{
    private:

    typedef std::tuple<int,int,double> Args;

    //default arguments
    static constexpr const Args defaults = std::make_tuple(10,52,0.5);
    Args args;
    public :
    f_():args(defaults)
    {}

    template <int n,class T> f_& setArg(T&& t)
    {
        std::get<n>(args) = t;
        return *this;
    }

    void operator()() 
    {
        return (*this)(std::move(args));
    }

    void operator()(Args&& a)
    {
        int n1=std::get<0>(a);
        int n2=std::get<1>(a);
        double n3=std::get<2>(a);

        std::cout<<n1<<" "<<n2<<" "<<n3<<std::endl;
    }
};
#define set(n,v) setArg<n>((v))
int main()
{
    //f_().set<1>(42).set<3>("foo") ();
    f_().setArg<1>(42)(); //without Macro
    f_().set(0,666).set(1,42)(); //with Macro
    f_()(); //without any parameters
    f_()(std::forward_as_tuple(-21,-100,3.14)); //direct call
}
```

An alternative method is to use std::bind as described [there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible. 

However I would suggest you should **use parameters' datatype array** instead to achieve the scenario you gave. **You can overload** as well. If the datatypes of parameters varies then you should **define a class which has required parameters as members**. Pass the object of that class. It will not only solve your problem but also it is recommended from the perspective of maintainability as well.

Answer (score -2):

Probably this is something that you may be looking for, just a workaround !

```
/*
Function f() is called by passing 2 arguments. So to make sure that these 2 arguments are treated as
first and third, whereas the second and the fourth are taken as defaults:

SOLUTION 1 : using recursive call
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void f( int = 10,int = 20, int = 30, int = 40);

static int tempb;

static int flag = 1;

int main()
{
    cout << "calling function \n";
    //f();
    f(12,39);
}

void f( int a,int b,int c,int d )
{
    //static int flag = 1;
    //f();  
    if( flag == 1 )
    {
        --flag; 
        f();        //recursive call to intialize the variables a,b,c,d as per the prototype
        c = b;
        b = tempb;
        //cout << c;
    }
    else
    {
        tempb = b;
        return;
    }

    cout << endl <<"a = " << a  << endl << "b = "<< b << endl << "c = " << c << endl << "d = " << d << endl;
}
```

The following is another workaround may be this helps too !

```
/*
Function f() is called by passing 2 arguments. So to make sure that these 2 arguments are treated as
first and third, whereas the second and the fourth are taken as defaults:

SOLUTION 2 : using static variable

*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void f( int = 10,int = 20, int = 30, int = 40);

static int tempb;

int main()
{
    f();
    f(12,39);
}

void f( int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    static int flag = 1;

    if( flag == 1 )
    {
        --flag; 
        tempb = b;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        c = b;
        b = tempb;
    }

    cout << "a = " << a << endl << "b = " << b << endl << "c = " << c << endl << "d = " << d;
}
```

Comment: I can't go for the global static variable to select method parameters. Nobody should use that approach.